# Css - responsive split screen layout

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie to web development. I'm using react to create a responsive split screen signup page, but when I adjust the height of the screen size, the form can not be shown entirely. Does anyone know which part of my css is wrong or missing?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCv6I.png

The code is on the sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-bash-19wgq?file=/src/components/SignUp.js

Answer (score 0):

2 important things to notice:

1. 100vh as a height will give the element the height of the browser's window
2. overflow: when an element is higher than it's parent element, if the overflow is set to hidden, part of the content may not be visible.

I added a rule at the bottom regarding the screen height as such([here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-pine-srzkx?file=/src/components/SignUp.css:2668-2941) just for demo):

```
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
  .split-screen {
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.sign-up-container .right {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
}
.sign-up-container .left {
  min-height: 500px;
  }
}
```